# Google Places AutoCompleteFragment Theme change

Tags: android, google-places-autocomplete

I am using Google places AutoCompleteFragment with some dark background. The problem is default dark icons and text doesn't look good. So can I change both the icons that is search and cancel icon and also text color to light theme for clear visibility.

I have tried the method of typecasting to EditText box but using this method I can only change text colour. I want to change the whole theme to light.